# When two localy isometrical surfaces are globaly isometrical?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

> If S and S' are two regular localy isometrical surfaces and exists $\phi$ diffeomorphism between S and S' then S and S' are globaly isometrical.

Thats only true when $\phi$ is a global diffeomorphism?

Comment: Diffeomorphism is not enough, even for flat tori. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller_space. However, a diffeomorphism which is a local isometry is a global isometry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it only works when the diffeomorphism is global:

Consider for example a flat torus $S=T^2$ and take its universal cover $\tilde{S}$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the lifted Riemannian metric. Then, $S$ and $\tilde{S}$ are locally isometric (and hence, by definition, in particular locally diffeomorphic) but there cannot exist a global isometry between $S$ and $\tilde{S}$ since $S$ is compact while $\tilde{S}$ is not.